# Como fazer o programa escrever todas informações?

Tags: python-3.x

```
print('Bem-vindo!')
print()

numero_contas = int(input('Deseja registrar quantas contas: '))
x = 0

while x < numero_contas:
            x = x + 1
            conta = str(input('A conta é de qual site:'))                                  
            print()
            usuário = str(input('Digite o usuário:'))
            senha = str(input('Digite a senha: '))
            print()
            arq = open('Contas.txt', 'w')
            arq.write(conta)
            arq.write('\n')
            arq.write('Usuário: {}'.format(usuário))
            arq.write('\n')
            arq.write('Senha: {}'.format(senha))
            arq.write('\n')
            arq.close()
```

O problema é o seguinte: se por exemplo, eu digitar 2 na variável "conta", ele pede as informações normalmente, mas, quando eu abro o arquivo para verificar, ele só registra a primeira conta, se eu digito 3 na variável "conta", ele só registra a segunda conta, assim por diante.
Como eu posso resolver este problema?

Mais uma perguntinha básica, como eu posso fazer com que o programa, sempre que for executado, não tire os registros feitos anteriormente?
Por exemplo: Eu executei o programa, registrei somente uma conta.
Depois, eu executo o programa novamente, e registro duas contas, aí quando eu vou verificar, os dados da primeira execução sumiram, deixou somente os dados da segunda execução registrados. E eu quero que, ele registre todos os dados, sem excluir os dados das execuções anteriores, quero que ele junte com as próximas execuções.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É porque você está usando `w`, use `a` (um "extra" é que realmente não precisa abrir várias vezes o mesmo arquivo pode deixar o handle dele fora do `while`)

```
print('Bem-vindo!')
print()

numero_contas = int(input('Deseja registrar quantas contas: '))
x = 0

arq = open('Contas.txt', 'a')

while x < numero_contas:
    x = x + 1
    conta = str(input('A conta é de qual site:'))
    print()
    usuário = str(input('Digite o usuário:'))
    senha = str(input('Digite a senha: '))
    print()
    arq.write(conta)
    arq.write('\n')
    arq.write('Usuário: {}'.format(usuário))
    arq.write('\n')
    arq.write('Senha: {}'.format(senha))
    arq.write('\n')

arq.close()
```

Ou pode colocar o `open` se precisa que a cada vez que o programa iniciar ele gerar novamente a lista use assim:

```
print('Bem-vindo!')
print()

numero_contas = int(input('Deseja registrar quantas contas: '))
x = 0

arq = open('Contas.txt', 'w')

while x < numero_contas:
    x = x + 1
    conta = str(input('A conta é de qual site:'))
    print()
    usuário = str(input('Digite o usuário:'))
    senha = str(input('Digite a senha: '))
    print()

    arq.write(conta)
    arq.write('\n')
    arq.write('Usuário: {}'.format(usuário))
    arq.write('\n')
    arq.write('Senha: {}'.format(senha))
    arq.write('\n')

arq.close()
```

Comment: Opa, obrigado, resolveu o problema!!!

Comment: Então a função do "a" é para não precisar abrir o mesmo arquivo várias vezes?

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida, como eu posso fazer para abrir o arquivo em determinado lugar que eu desejo?

Comment: O `w` "apaga" (põe o ponteiro no começo) quando usa o `open` (não no write) e gera o conteudo do arquivo novamente, o `a` apenas adiciona no final do arquivo se existir. @BRKappa

Comment: É tipo por exemplo, quero que ele abra o arquivo que está em algum diretório, por exemplo: C:\Usuário\Diretório\Contas.txt

Comment: No open do python, por exemplo: Estou com o arquivo Contas.TXT no diretório: C:\Documentos\Pasta_Teste\Contas.txt. Eu quero abrir o arquivo "Contas.TXT" que está neste diretório.

Comment: @BRKappa creio que seria isto em windows `open('c:/Documentos/Pasta_Teste/Contas.txt', 'a')` e isto em Linux `open('/home/user/Documentos/Pasta_Teste/Contas.txt', 'a')`

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu todos os meus problemas!!!!

Comment: @BRKappa ;D por nada